# Testing a json service

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, junit

Although below test works fine in one enviroment how can the test be modified so that it does not depend on what server the
getJson() service is running on ?

Do I need to create a mock Spring json object so that it does not matter what the domain name is (in this case its `http://myapplication`) ?

```
 @Test
    public void jsonResponse() throws Exception
    {

URL oracle = new URL("http://myapplication/newJson.json");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    String json;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        json += inputLine;
    in.close();

    }

    My controller class is defined like : 

        @Controller
    @RequestMapping("myservice")
    public class Controller {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/newJson.json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody String getJson() {
            return "{ test:testJson}";
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc). Or if you don't want an additional dependency, you can write a unit test calling the controller directly, as opposed to through an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) and mock the URLConnection.